# Get a worksheet name using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create an `user-defined` function in `Excel` that can return the current worksheet.  I could use the

```
sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
```

But the problem with this is, it works and suddenly it starts to get different sheet name. For example, instead of `SHEET I LOVE YOU` it returns `SHEET I HATE YOU`.

Is there anyway to fix this - or it might possible because I think it can not be static but varies?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
Function MySheet()

  ' uncomment the below line to make it Volatile
  'Application.Volatile
   MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name

End Function
```

This should be the function you are looking for

Answer (score 16):

This works for me.

```
worksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: Note that this requires the active sheet to be selected. If you're stepping through code in the VBA editor and get to this line, you'll get an "Error 424: Object Required" (or similar) alert because no sheet is active; the VBA editor is active. However, when you run this code inside a module from a keyboard shortcut or the Macros list window, it will work.

Comment: If you have more than one sheet using this, all the sheets will have the name of the active sheet, which is the problem the op was trying to avoid

Answer (score 7):

```
Sub FnGetSheetsName()

    Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

    Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    For i = 1 To mainworkBook.Sheets.Count

    'Either we can put all names in an array , here we are printing all the names in Sheet 2

    mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i) = mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend Code for Show Selected Sheet(s) [ one or more sheets].

```
Sub Show_SelectSheet()
  For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     For Each xSelectSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
         If xSheet.Name = xSelectSheet.Name Then
            '=== Show Selected Sheet ===
            GoTo xNext_SelectSheet
         End If
     Next xSelectSheet
  xSheet.Visible = False  
xNext_SelectSheet:
Next xSheet
MsgBox "Show Selected Sheet(s) Completed !!!"
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Sub getsheetnames()
 Dim current As Worksheet
 Dim sheetname As String
 Dim i As Integer
 
i = 0

    For Each current In Worksheets
        i = i + 1
        sheetname = current.Name
        Debug.Print sheetname
        Debug.Print i
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            Range("A" & i).Value = sheetname
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to get the Active Sheet name and change it to yours preferred name.

```
Sub ChangeSheetName()

Dim shName As String
Dim currentName As String
currentName = ActiveSheet.Name
shName = InputBox("What name you want to give for your sheet")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(currentName).Name = shName

End Sub
```