# link tab name of a worksheet to a cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel

how can I link the tab name of an excel sheet to a cell? Do I have to write a macro with VBA? or can I use a function therefore?

*Why I need this is: When I change the name of the tab I want to take it on for a cell in another worksheet.*

thx all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323343/get-a-worksheet-name-using-excel-vba

Comment: thx for your answer @Vityata. But I think my question was not clear enough :/. I tried the link from you but it does not work. I have a tab name this tab name has the same name as a cell in on other worksheet. And when I change the tab name I automatically want to change the name in the cell..

Answer (score 2):

Write the following formula:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))
```

When you change the name of the worksheet, it will change.
About the CELL worksheet function, read more here:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CellWorksheetFunctions.aspx

You actually have to write `=CELL("filename")` to get the name of the tab plus the path of the worksheet. And "filename" should be written.

Comment: so I have to link this formular to the cell where the same content is right? @vityata

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't understand the Formular :-( and I really don't know where to include this.

Comment: @flowers1234 - just put it somewhere in the excel sheet. It would return the name of the worksheet.

Comment: "filename" is the name of the tab name right? Sorry for these stupid questions but it's not working :/

Comment: @flowers1234 - No. See the edit. There is a nice article there.