# Create visible formula through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My challenge is to code a visible formula into cells that end-users can read the reference. Highlighted yellow line of code causes error **"Application Defined or Order defined error"**. The requirement is that in cells are simple formula like below, which takes first number from workbook where actual result will be and other one comes from different workbook. Actual code locates in a third excel.

> ```
> =5/78
> ```

**Variables**

- `Private AR As New Dimension`
- `Private UR As New Dimension`
- `UR.KeySheet` --> `Sheet 1`
- `AR.KeySheet` --> `DivederNumbers`
- `UR.Wb` --> `myWorkbook.xlxs`
- `AR.Wb` --> `myOtherWorkbook.xlxs`

.

```
Dim test As String

If AR.Wb.Sheets(AR.KeySheet).Cells(Cell3.Row, Cell2.Column) > 0 Then

    test = AR.Wb.Path & "\" & AR.Wb.Name

    '**THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR:
    UR.Wb.Sheets("RESULT").Cells(Cell1.Row, Cell1.Column).Formula = _
        "='" & UR.KeySheet & "'!" & Cells(Cell1.Row, Cell1.Column).Address & "/" _
        & "'" & [test] & AR.KeySheet & "'!" & Cells(Cell1.Row, _
        Cell1.Column).Address(External:=True)

    Exit For

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a sheet like that. `AR.KeySheet` is only valid as part of the `Sheets()` collection.

Here is a solution for referencing the sheet name: [Get a worksheet name using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323343/get-a-worksheet-name-using-excel-vba)

You would need to use:

```
"='" & Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & Cells(Cell1.row, Cell1.column).Address & "/" _
```